# How to post questions in sencha forum?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, forum

i like to post some questions in sencha forum. I created account in sencha touch.Could anyone guide me **How to post questions in Sencha forum ?** Because i'm new to sencha forum. Don't mistake me friends.

Comment: i don't know why and who reduce negative vote to my question ? Please could any one explain me then only i can correct myself !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [REGISTER](https://www.sencha.com/forum/register.php) as a Sencha user -

after that you can [LOGIN](https://www.sencha.com/forum/login.php?do=login) and post any questions

Comment: thank for your reply. i already created login.  i want to post my question in that form. Now only i found out. 

Step 1 : Click community which is based on our question.

Step 2 : Search your question related thread is already posted in that forum.

Step 3 : If not Click **Post New Thread** and post our question.

thats all. :)